# Probability of mixture distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, mixture-distribution, inequality

Let
\begin{equation}
p_1=\Pr(0.8z_1^2+0.2z_2^2 > c), \qquad p_2=\Pr(0.2z_1^2+0.2z_2^2 > c),
\end{equation}
where $z_1,z_2 \sim N(0,1)$.

Then, can I have $p_1 >p_2$ since $0.8z_1^2+0.2z_2^2 > 0.2z_1^2+0.2z_2^2$ ?

Comment: This is not a mixture distribution, but a convolution distribution.

Comment: @Henry Your point is obscure.  The OP has observed that one event is a superset of the other and asks whether that implies the probability of the first exceeds that of the second.  Intuitively this is obvious, but a rigorous demonstration must show that for a bivariate distribution with marginal Normal distributions, the probability of the difference of these events is positive. That's not completely obvious unless you assume the $z_i$ are not perfectly correlated.

Comment: @whuber I had misread the question.  And I suspect you are right that it is possible to get $p_1=p_2$ if $c$ is small enough and you manipulate the joint distribution so you do not get moderate magnitude $z_1$ and $z_2$ at the same time and there may be other examples